# How to display a Controller array in twig template

Tags: php, symfony, twig

product.html.twig:

```
<ul id="navigation">                 
    <li>
        <a href="<?php echo product.getId() ?>">
            <?php echo product.getDescription() ?>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Controller Action method contains:

```
public function showAction($id = 5)
{
    $product = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('AppBundle:Product')
        ->find($id);

    if (!$product) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException(
            'No product found for id '.$id
        );
    }
    else 
    {
        return $this->render('default/productItem.html.twig', array(
            'id'=> $id,
            'name' => $name));
    }
}
```

I cant see the output in the list

Comment: Is it an array that is holding an object? Is `$product` an object?

Comment: why not with  `href="{{ product.id }}" `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the Twig syntax.

```
<ul id="navigation">                 
    <li>
        <a href="/page.php?id={{ product.getId() }}">
            {{ product.getDescription() }}
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

In your case your input have to be an object. With the functions `getId()` and `getDescription()`.

In your code you can remove "get" and write only `{{ product.id }}` for example.

Answer (score 0):

Would suggest some changes to your Controller:

In your controller you hard code your `$id` parameter to "5'. It's probably better to use routing annotation and have an optional parameter instead. Use the `defaults` to hardcode any default value.

Also, instead of `$id`, I suggest you call it `$productID`, so you know it is for a Product Entity, and to distinguish it from what you pass in the array (as a parameter) to your twig controller.

Also in your sample code you show passing in the parameter of `id` and `name`, but firstly `$name` is not defined anywhere, and `$id` is what you pass in as a parameter to the Controller, but then in your twig file you don't show using either of `name` or `id` at all! Plus you render `productItem.html.twig`, but above the post you call it `product.html.twig`. So is that a different file?

Make sure when you post question on Stackoverflow that everything is clear.

Here is sample of how you might change you controller code as per my suggestions above:

```
/**
 * @Route("/showproduct/{productID}",
 *      defaults={"productID" = 0},
 *      name="showproduct
 */
public function showAction($productID)
{
    $product = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('AppBundle:Product')
        ->find($productID);

    if (!$product) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException(
            'No product found for id '.$productID
        );
    }
    else 
    {
        return $this->render('default/productItem.html.twig', array(
            'product'=> $product,
        ));
    }
}
```

---

Then in your twig file (is it `productItem.html.twig`???) then like this:

```
<ul id="navigation">                 
    <li>
        <a href="{{ product.getId }}">
            {{ product.getDescription }}
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Hope it helps!